# Pexpect ingress trace collection

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pexpect

Hie,

My use case :
my pexpect script establishes a telnet session to box1,
some person pings box1 from any box2,
ingress ip debugs are applied on box1,
i need to collect ingress trace from box1.

my ques :
now that we know, 
pexpect's paradigm is a combination of sendline-expect-print child.before,
but in this case,
we aren't explicitly running cmd, rather, 
some box2 is sending cmd,
So, how do i collect trace in child.before even if we haven't run sendline or expect, for that matter.

Thanks

Comment: it's more of a technology based generic ques, hence, din't put up any code.
but feel free to ask for it, i'l add the code.

Comment: Learnt by hit & trial that 
<code>
child.expect("<box_name>")
child.timeout = <a large num>
child.expect("<box_name>")
</code>

this way, even live traffic running wrt some pid/fd can be traced by python. So, ques is solved.